# How to find position of breakpoint visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

how do you find the position in a project's source files a program is at when a breakpoint is triggered in visual studio 2012?

For example, if I tried to use delete() on an uninitialised pointer the program would break in a windows memory file or an assembly file; how do I find the position in the project source, i.e. the point where delete() was called upon hitting the breakpoint?

Thanks

Comment: There is a "Call Stack" window in VS (usually in bottom right-hand corner, or available through Debug menu). If you're building with debug info, your functions will be listed on the call stack.

Comment: @Angew it would be better if you make it as answer.